# Flexslider issue with the width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

The website is http://teothemes.com/wp/Teo/ and the section I'm reffering is the Portfolio section with the filterable portfolio. On hover on each element, two icons show up http://prntscr.com/1a1wxx

If you click on the "+" one(which means extend), the slider is totally messed up, http://prntscr.com/1a1x00 . I don't understand why it takes all the images in just one slide. And, it happens just on the first time I load a portfolio, if I try it for other portfolio items after I open the first ope, it works just fine.

I've tried setting the position to relative, thought it's a css problem with margins, padding, the width of the top container, I set it to 100%, but it just doesn't want to work.

I think the problem is with some of the default CSS code for the flexslider container, but I'm not sure what exactly to check.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a script that is making the width of every list element 30px

Comment: what script? I checked it with firebug and I don't see anything like that

Comment: i dont know what script, i dont have the code, but try debugging with Chrome DevTools

Comment: Flexslider is the one setting the width to 30px or so, that's the actual problem I have

Comment: Ok so try editing it to set the width to 100% or so.